# Select Element of Dropdown Box in wicket with dynamically created elements

Tags: java, wicket

How can I automatically select an element in my dropdown box that I'm creating and adding?
The code below creates the dropdown box, I would like to select the item that corresponds to the LanguageFormat property in my ExportConfiguration object.

Edit: The answer I've accepted turned me on to the right track.  I had to declare the property in the values list which caused it to automatically be assigned.  Thanks!

```
(Solution)
values.put(
    "exportConfigurationLanguageFormat",exportConfiguration.getLanguageFormat());

(/Solution)

//Language Format choices
ArrayList<String> languageFormatArray = new ArrayList<String>();

languageFormatArray.add(firstLanguage);
languageFormatArray.add(firstLanguage + "-" + firstLanguage.toUpperCase());
languageFormatArray.add(firstLanguage + "_" + firstLanguage.toUpperCase());           

exportConfigurationLanguageFormat = new DropDownChoice<String>(
    "exportConfigurationLanguageFormat", new PropertyModel<String>
    (values, "exportConfigurationLanguageFormat"), languageFormatArray);
exportConfigurationLanguageFormat.setRequired(true);

exportConfigurationLanguageFormatFeedback.add(exportConfigurationLanguageFormat);
```

Comment: That's a nice suggestion, @BorisPavlović, you can learn *a lot* peeking at the Wicket sources. Always more reliable than the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have a solution that works now, but I'll remember it for next time.  I do like poking through source code to get a better idea how it works, just wish I had more time for it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should occur automatically if the `exportConfigurationLanguageFormat` property of the `values` object matches one of the entries in `languageFormatArray` when the page is rendered.

I would suggest checking that `languageFormatArray.contains(values.getExportConfigurationLanguageFormat())`.

Answer (score 1):

As @andypandy [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817697/select-element-of-dropdown-box-in-wicket-with-dynamically-created-elements/7817820#7817820), the `DropDownChoice` will be retrieveing/storing its value in relation to the property `exportConfigurationLanguageFormat` of the `values` object.

Make sure it already has a value, and also important, make sure that its value is one of the values in the `DropDownChoice`'s choices. Actually id should be sufficient if their `equals()` returns true.